# .NET application running on Linux reaches Tasks limit

Tags: .net, linux, systemd

I have a `.NET 6` application hosted on `Linux's` `systemd`. Lately I have been having problems with service restarting itself and just noticed that `Tasks` reaches its limit which is over `10k`. Any ideas where could the problem lie?
Not sure what information I should provide in order to understand this better, waiting for feedback.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What tasks do you refer to? What is the application doing? System.Threading.Tasks.Task isn't a thread, it's a Promise that may or may not run on a pooled thread. .NET itself doesn't generate threads for no reason. All tasks started with `Task.Run` will run on a thread that comes from a pool of reusable threads. Threads can't run if there are no CPU cores to run them, so starting 10K tasks is simply an application bug

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Tasks' count is displayed when using `systemctl status service-name.service`, not really familiar with what it is. It is more of a `linux` task rather than .NET application itself I imagine. It is just that application cause that many tasks to be opened and not closed if that is what should happen.
Application is basically an `API` receiving requests from the website and returning data from database. Making few request increases tasks for over 100 or even more.